# How to delete a queue in YARN?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, capacity

I see a queue in the yarn configuration file that I want to delete:

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.queues</name>
  <value>a,b,c</value>
  <description>The queues at the this level (root is the root queue).
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.a.queues</name>
  <value>a1,a2</value>
  <description>The queues at the this level (root is the root queue).
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.b.queues</name>
  <value>b1,b2,b3</value>
  <description>The queues at the this level (root is the root queue).
  </description>
</property>
```

Say I want to remove queue `c`.  I remove `c` from the list under the line `<name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.queues</name>` so that line looks like this:

```
<value>a,b,c</value>
```

Then I go to the command line and run `yarn rmadmin -refreshQueues`.

But I get the following error message:

```
Caused by java.io.IOException: c cannot be found during refresh!`
```

I'm trying to delete the queue `c`.  How do I delete it?

I noticed [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html#Configuration) it says that

> Note: Queues cannot be deleted, only addition of new queues is
>   supported - the updated queue configuration should be a valid one i.e.
>   queue-capacity at each level should be equal to 100%.

...so, how do I delete a queue if I don't need it anymore?

thanks.

Comment: From that page: "Administrators can add additional queues at runtime, but queues cannot be deleted at runtime." It sounds like  you cannot delete at runtime, BUT you can stop/kill the YARN, update the config file (and remove `c`) and run YARN with the new configuration.

Comment: That is a known issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-4022

Comment: @arash how do I stop yarn?

Answer (score 3):

From that page:

> Administrators can add additional queues at runtime, but queues cannot be deleted at **runtime**.

It sounds like you cannot delete at runtime, BUT you can stop/kill the YARN, update the config file (and remove `c`) and run YARN with the new configuration. So if you can afford to stop/start the YARN then here is the process:

**Note**: Before killing the YARN Read [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRestart.html) on the effects on the system depending on your YARN version.

Here goes the process:

> Stop the MapReduce JobHistory service, ResourceManager service, and NodeManager on all nodes where they are running, as follows:

```
 sudo service hadoop-mapreduce-historyserver stop
 sudo service hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager stop
 sudo service hadoop-yarn-nodemanager stop
```

Then Edit the config file and remove `c`

> Start the MapReduce JobHistory server, ResourceManager, and NodeManager on all nodes where they were previously running, as follows:

```
 sudo service hadoop-mapreduce-historyserver start
 sudo service hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager start
 sudo service hadoop-yarn-nodemanager start
```

Commands are from [here](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/cdh_hag_rm_ha_config.html#concept_kmk_2vy_vl)

Comment: @Sother for making other changes  (like `add`) but not for `delete`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to stop Yarn if you want to delete a queue. Only `add`, `update` and `stop` is supported while Yarn is running.

Comment: how do I stop yarn?

Comment: and if I stop it, will it kill all of my applications running?

Comment: No, Yarn won't immediately kill you apps. Once you stop a queue, no more app can be added to it, and yarn will wait for all apps on this queue completed. You can see the [official tutorial](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html) for more details.

Comment: That isn't true.  I just tried it.  YARN does actually kill your applications if you restart `hadoop-yarn-nodemanager` while the application is running